# jQuery - Rotate an image by a static amount, and then apply a drop shadow?

Tags: jquery, rotation

Can anyone give me a jQuery example of how to:

1. Rotate an image by a static number of degrees (say 30 degrees)
2. Apply a drop-shadow effect to the rotated image

Comment: What's wrong with doing this with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@genesis' answer doesn't seem to support Internet Explorer, as the DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=) parameter only supports 90, 180, and 270 degree increments (docs here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

A better solution I've found is to use a combination of @genesis' answer, and a jQuery plugin found here:
 http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Use the jQuery code to rotate the image by whatever amount:

```
$('#photo1').rotate(-8);
```

And then use this modification of @genesis' code to apply the drop-shadow:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
```

The modification doesn't include this line:

```
box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
```

Because including that line gets you an ugly black background in Internet Explorer for some reason. It seems to work fine without it.

Answer (score 2):

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
box-shadow:2px 2px 4px #999999;
```

will do it

Comment: Is there by chance a way to make the image anti-alias against whatever it's overlayed over? So that you don't see the hard pixels of the rotation?

Comment: Oh and- this works GREAT!  (except it'd be even greater if it would anti-alias)

Comment: @KeithPalmer: I'm afraid - no, not as long as you rely on browser

Comment: @Keith probably, because IE is not so good one. I think you'll everytime have problems with IE :/

Comment: Unfortunately, 35%+ of our web traffic is IE, so a solution that doesn't work in IE just isn't work-able. See my answer below for a solution that works in IE as well.